# I need access to my Google Analytics which was set up by a third party

Tags: google-analytics, accounts

I have hired a new advertising company and they need access to my Google Analytics acct. I believe this was set up by Thryv about 7 months ago but they will only give me my acct number and not log in info.
what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Thryv would not be able to give you your login information, as GA login would be done via your Google Account login.

Do you have any access to the GA Account that Thryv setup for you via your Google Account login?

If not, do you have more than one Google Account, or more than one email address associated with your Google Account?
If so, I would try each of them to access an existing GA Account.

If that fails, you can submit a GA Account Recovery request, however bare in mind they are not always successful, as there is are strict requirements due to security and privacy of data.

Relevant details and link to the submission form can be found on the following page:
https://support.google.com/analytics/troubleshooter/7264014?hl=en#ts=7271146